# Pre-process varying image sizes in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, image, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a batch of images with varying sizes such as (375, 500,3), (200, 147, 3)..etc.

Before these are fed to the CNN, I need to process them to have a standard size and probably distort them a bit.

What should be the approach to do so?

So far I have tried the below, but this makes large images look crappy.

```
  def preprocess_1 (images, labels):
      images = tf.image.central_crop(images, 0.9)
      images = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(images, 255, 255)
      return images, labels
```

Comment: You can try Keras' [Image Generator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) for augmenting images according to you. I have gotten pretty good results using it so far.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions I can think of:

1. It seems to me that you want to get square images. You could first turn the rectangular images into square images by filling zero's in the blanks. You can then resize all the square images into a required size.
2. You can refer to the paper `Spatial Pyramid Pooling in Deep Convolutional Networks for Visual Recognition`, this method adds a Spatial Pyramid Pooling Layer to solve the problem of images with different sizes.